# How can I list products on a static page that are tagged by a tag that has the same name as my page?

Tags: shopify, liquid, shopify-liquid

I'd like to list products on my static page called "Haarentfernung". Each product that should be featured has a same named tag called "Haarentfernung".

So far I've managed to get the Products with the tag 'Haarentfernung'.

```
{% paginate collections.all.products by 999 %}
   {%- assign allItems = collections.all.products -%}
     {%- for items in allItems -%}
       {% assign testItem = items.tags | where: 'Haarentfernung'%}
         <p>{{ testItem }}test1</p> 
     {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

However I'd like to make it dynamic with the element `page.title`. But using {{ page.title }} inside the where filter doesn't work

```
{% paginate collections.all.products by 999 %}
   {%- assign allItems = collections.all.products -%}
     {%- for items in allItems -%}
       {% assign testItem = items.tags | where: {{ page.title }} %}
         <p>{{ testItem }}test1</p> 
     {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

also doesn't work with when in apostrophes

```
{% paginate collections.all.products by 999 %}
   {%- assign allItems = collections.all.products -%}
     {%- for items in allItems -%}
       {% assign testItem = items.tags | where: '{{ page.title }}' %}
         <p>{{ testItem }}test1</p> 
     {% endfor %}
{% endpaginate %}
```

Is there a solution that is simpler? Maybe totally different approach?

Comment: Yes, create a collection view, and request the view with tagged using AJAX and append the result on the page.

Comment: used the new theme 2.0 template and mange the product listing using metaobjects

Answer (score 0):

the `{{...}}` is for rendering to HTML for the front end. It does not change `{{page.title}}` to a string in `{% assign testItem = items.tags | where: {{ page.title }} %}`

Remove the `{{...}}` in `{{page.title}}` will work.